# Printing the 2 highest numbers in an Array

Tags: java, arrays

So I created a method called max2 that is supposed to return the 2 highest values in an array. I am able to return the highest value however I cannot figure out how to return the second highest value.

Here is my code: 
   Main Method

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer intArray[] = { 13, 25, 46, 65, 12, 23};
        Double doubleArray[] = {1.2, 3.4, 1.1, 0.1, 5.6};
        String stringArray[] = {"H", "E", "L", "L", "O"};

    System.out.println("The smallest number is: " + myMin(doubleArray));
    System.out.println("The median is: " + median(doubleArray));
    System.out.println("The median is: " + median(stringArray));
    System.out.println("The max is: " + max2(intArray));
}
```

My max2 method:

```
public static <E extends Comparable<E>> E max2(E... elements) {

Arrays.sort(elements);

    E max = elements[0];
    for (E element : elements) {
        if (element.compareTo(max) > 0) {
            max = element;

        }
    }
    return max;

}
```

I am wondering if there is a way to get the 2nd to last index of the array. Ideally I would want this to work with any array. I am looking to be pointed into the right direction. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You need to remember both at the same time when traversing, not only the highest. But also the second highest candidate. Alternatively, sort the array and pick the second element. Or do a 2-sort (k-sort). Or you use your method to identify the highest element, remove it, and identify the highest again.

Comment: `Arrays.sort(elements);` - Numbers are, by default, sorted **ascending**. `elements[0]` is not the greatest, but the smallest element. The greatest is `elements[elements.length - 1]` and the second to greatest is `elements[elements.length - 2]`. Please do some debugging, just add some `System.out.println(...)` to your code to inspect it. You could have easily found that out yourself.

Comment: ok this makes a lot of sense! thank you! And just to clarify, if I remove that element (the highest one) I could just redo what I already did and return the 2nd largest correct?

Comment: you can remove elements from array

Comment: @Deadpool how exactly do I remove an element from an array?

Comment: why do you want to remove? what do you want to do exactly? you want to remove duplicates ?

Comment: no If you read Zabuza's answer he said I can identify the highest element, remove it, and then  identify the highest element again. That way I can return both the Highest element, then the 2nd highest.

Comment: no technically you can't remove elements from array, if you like to do in that approach you should try some collections `ArrayList` etc..

Comment: Arrays are fixed-sized structures. Technically you can't *remove* something (in a sense of changing the size). But you could set the item to something very small, like `Integer.MIN_VALUE`. However, I don't see any sense in doing all of this as you already did a **full sort**. So you can directly access the second to greatest element. Note that you don't need a full sort at all, you could traverse the array and remember the current greatest and second to greatest candidate while you are traversing.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Java 8 streams to remove duplicates and sort the array, and use `length-1` and `length-2` to get max and second max element from array

```
Integer intArray[] = { 13,13, 25, 46,25, 65, 12, 23};
    Double doubleArray[] = {1.2, 3.4, 1.1, 0.1, 5.6};
    String stringArray[] = {"H", "E", "L", "L", "O"};

   Integer[] s= Arrays.stream(intArray).sorted().distinct().toArray(Integer[]::new);
   System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s));
   int max = s[s.length-1];
   int max2 = s[s.length-2];
```

or if you just want to sort array then you should use `Arrays.sort` to sort array and get the max and second max element

```
Arrays.sort(intArray) 
int max = s[s.length-1];
int max2 = s[s.length-2];
```

Comment: Note that a **full sort** is not required to get the second to greatest element.

Answer (score 0):

we need to sort an array on descending order you can use bubble sort, now we can get the last index value as highest number  and second last index as second highest number.
example.

```
class ReturnTwoHeighestNumber {
  public static void main(String...args) {
   int arr[] = {12,13,15,6,9,30,50,19};
   ReturnTwoHeighestNumber number = new ReturnTwoHeighestNumber();
   number.bubleSort(arr);
   number.printTwohighestNumber(arr)   
  }
  void bubleSort(int arr[]) {
  int n= arr.length;
   for(int i=0; j<n-1;i++) {
      for(int j=0;j<n-i-1; j++) {
         if(arr[j]> arr[j+1]) {
          int temp = arr[1];
          arr[j] = arr[j+1];
          arr[j+1] = temp;
         }
      }
   }
  void printTwohighestNumber(int arr[]) {
    int n= arr.length;
    for(int j=0;j<n;++j) {
      System.out.print(arr[j]+" ");
      System.out.println();  
    }
     System.out.println("My first highest Number is "+ arr[arr.length-1]);
     System.out.println("My Second highest Number is "+arr[arr.length-2]);   
  }    

  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Your approach

Your current approach doesn't make much sense. You have

```
Arrays.sort(elements);

E max = elements[0];
for (E element : elements) {
    if (element.compareTo(max) > 0) {
        max = element;
    }
}
return max;
```

That is, you first sort the array. And then you traverse all elements to find the *max*-element. First, you wanted to find the second to max element, not the max element. And second, why are you sorting when you then don't exploit the fact that it is sorted, but just iterate through the array?

Let me show you some solutions.

---

### Full sort

Probably the easiest solution is to do a **full sort** and then access the second to last element (elements are sorted ascending by default):

```
Arrays.sort(values);
return values[values.length - 2];
```

There is one problem with this approach. `Arrays.sort` sorts the given array inline. That is, it changes your input array. You probably do not want this and only want to sort a copy. So:

```
E[] copyValues = values.clone();
Arrays.sort(copyValues);
return copyValues[copyValues.length - 2];
```

---

### Partial sort

Instead of doing a full sort, you can always do a partial sort (k-sort). This will be faster, as you only need to sort the array descending for 2 elements. You can do a partial sort using a `PriorityQueue`. Insert all elements into the queue and then call `poll` two times. The queue always gives you the next element according to the order.

```
PriorityQueue<E> queue = new PriorityQueue<>(Comparator.reverseOrder());
queue.addAll(Arrays.asList(values);

queue.poll(); // Greatest element
return queue.poll(); // Second to greatest element
```

---

### Iteration

Probably the fastest solution is to do one ordinary iteration and remembering the greatest, as well as the second to greatest element. This is similar to the loop in your approach, but including remembering the second to greatest element.

```
E max = values[0];
E secondMax = values[0];

for (E element : elements) {
    if (element.compareTo(max) > 0) {
        secondMax = max;
        max = element;
    } else if (element.compareTo(secondMax) > 0) {
        secondMax = element;
    }
}

return secondMax;
```

Note that you need to remember the `max` element too, since you want to find an element that is not greater than `max`, but still greater than the rest.